# Как работают команды при разработке ПО?

Tags: работа

Мы с друзьями решили заняться разработкой ПО под андроид. Есть интересные идеи, но если честно, не понятно с чего начинать, т.к. опыт работы есть, но в сфере 1С, и никто не работал в командах. Подскажите, плз.

Comment: Мы с кэпом решили, что надо выбрать лучшую идею и НАЧАТЬ её http://programming-motherfucker.com/

Answer (score 1):

Определитесь с структурой команды, четко установите кто какую роль выполняет и какие у него обязанности (кто руководитель проекта, кто ведет разработку справочной документации, кто пишет код и т.п.)

Сделайте документацию проекта, опишите все в деталях, убедитесь что каждый член команды понимает задачу и проект полностью.

Разделите проект на подзадачи (документация, разработка пользовательского интерфейса, написание кода, тестирование, выпуск продукта).

Установите сроки для каждой подзадачи (сроки сразу умножайте на 2).

Лучше начинать с небольшого проекта (сроком на 2-3 месяца), чтобы во-первых прошла "притирка" команды и во-вторых быстрее увидеть результат своей работы.

П.С. И да.. главное, если команда не наемная, чтобы амбиции не мешали реализации поставленной задачи. Удачи! )

Comment: Спасибо за совет.)))) Будем стараться